# how to perform ontology based image retrieval using protege tool

Tags: ontology, protege

I have created an ontology using the protege tool. How can we perform ontology based image retrieval after creating an ontology. Please give suggestion, my project is semantic based image retrieval. Which language and software should I use

Comment: Too broadly scoped for a precise answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Link below to see the information retrieval by using protege http://protege.stanford.edu/conference/2003/Claudio_Duque_MancFinalF.pdf